# How can I add condition based on select value (JSONB) on PostgreSQL 12?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I want to filter rows that have `gold` badges. I am using PG12 and I use new path feature of it.

To clarify, I have a `users_tbl` table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users_tbl (
   ID serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   data jsonb NOT NULL
);
```

And lets insert values:

```
INSERT INTO users_tbl (ID, data) values (1, '{"badges": ["gold", "silver"], "another_field": 1}');
INSERT INTO users_tbl (ID, data) values (2, '{"badges": ["silver"], "another_field": 3}');
INSERT INTO users_tbl (ID, data) values (3, '{"badges": ["gold"], "another_field": 4}');
```

Now when I query like this:

```
SELECT
  ID, jsonb_path_query("data", '$.badges') AS "badges"
FROM "users_tbl";
```

I get following result as expected:

```
+----+--------------------+
+ ID |       badges       +
+----+--------------------+
+ 1  | ["gold", "silver"] +
+----+--------------------+
+ 2  | ["silver"]         +
+----+--------------------+
+ 3  | ["gold"]           +
+----+--------------------+
```

Now list only have `badge` matches `gold`

```
SELECT
  jsonb_path_query("data", '$.badges') AS "badges"
FROM "users_tbl"
WHERE "badges" @> 'gold';
```

### Expected result:

```
+----+--------------------+
+ ID |       badges       +
+----+--------------------+
+ 1  | ["gold", "silver"] +
+----+--------------------+
+ 3  | ["gold"]           +
+----+--------------------+
```

### Actual Result:

```
column "badges" does not exist
```

How can I add condition against `badges`? Or am I doing something not correct? How can I get expected result in my case?

**Note**: PostgreSQL 12.

## Update:

Actually in this example I've used a simple jsonb object. In reality its like this:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "badges": ["gold", "silver"]
  }
}
```

So, `badges` are in `properties`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the containment operator:

```
select
    jsonb_path_query(data, '$.badges') as badges
from users_tbl
where data->'badges' @> '"gold"';
```

or `jsonb_path_exists()`:

```
select
    jsonb_path_query(data, '$.badges') as badges
from users_tbl
where jsonb_path_exists(data, '$.badges ? (@[*] == "gold")')
```

Comment: I've made an update at the bottom. Can you inspect it please?

Comment: No need to inspect. I just added secondary path and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `?` operator:

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query("data", '$.badges') AS "badges"
FROM "users_tbl"
WHERE "data" -> 'badges' ? 'gold';
```

Note: I am unsure that you do need `jsonb_path_query()` here. This is a set-returning function that does not really seems to make sense in your context. Your query could probably be phrased:

```
SELECT "data" ->> 'badges' AS "badges"
FROM "users_tbl"
WHERE "data" -> 'badges' ? 'gold';
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=13eee5f5dcfdf8f3de68879b36a06e25)**:

```
| badges             |
| :----------------- |
| ["gold", "silver"] |
| ["gold"]           |
```

Comment: I've made an update at the bottom. Can you inspect it please?

Comment: @Pratha: that would be: `SELECT "data" -> 'properties' ->> 'badges' AS "badges"
FROM "users_tbl"
WHERE "data" -> 'properties' -> 'badges' ? 'gold';`

Comment: Thanks. I just can't decide if I should go with your or `jsonb_path_exists` from @klin's answer. This column can be `NULL`, can be empty or may not have properties/badges at all. Does this matters on yours?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I add condition against `badges`?

You can't really. As the error message says, it's not a column of the table - that's what you'd need to refer to in the `WHERE` clause. You cannot take the selection alias to refer to the result value of the expression. You could repeat it

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query_first("data", '$.badges') AS "badges"
FROM "users_tbl"
WHERE jsonb_path_query_first("data", '$.badges') @> 'gold';
```

or use a `LATERAL` subquery:

```
SELECT badges
FROM "users_tbl", LATERAL jsonb_path_query("data", '$.badges') as badges
WHERE badges @> 'gold';
```

Comment: I got `set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE` on first query of yours.

Comment: @Pratha Oh, I forgot that `jsonb_path_query` is a set-returning function - you only expect one array value back. I've changed it to use `jsonb_path_query_first`, although definitely I would suggest using the simple `->` operator as in the other answers, a `jsonpath` is overkill here. (I just wanted the code to resemble your original more)